# Python: Create new column that numbers how many occurrences has taken place from another column

Tags: python, pandas

Just for a basic understanding of what I am referring too, the `frequency` column is what I am trying to create, based on the number of times fruits has appeared prior to that given row

| Fruit | Frequency | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 |  |
| Banana | 1 |  |
| Orange | 1 |  |
| Apple | 2 |  |
| Apple | 3 |  |
| Orange | 2 |  |

I tried `df['Frequency']=df.groupby['fruit', 'date'].cumcount()` but could not get it to work

Comment: What's in your `Date` column? It looks empty in your question. Is it relevant (i.e.: are "prior rows" with regard to `Date` by any chance)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```py
newdf = df.assign(Frequency=df.groupby('Fruit').cumcount() + 1)
>>> newdf
    Fruit  Frequency  Date
0   Apple          1   NaN
1  Banana          1   NaN
2  Orange          1   NaN
3   Apple          2   NaN
4   Apple          3   NaN
5  Orange          2   NaN
```